# Calculate weighted average of four nearest grid points

Tags: r

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
   Teff  logg M_div_H       U       B      V      R      I     J     H     K     L Lprime     M
 1: 2000  4.00    -0.1 -13.443 -11.390 -7.895 -4.464 -1.831 1.666 3.511 2.701 4.345  4.765 5.680
 2: 2000  4.50    -0.1 -13.402 -11.416 -7.896 -4.454 -1.794 1.664 3.503 2.728 4.352  4.772 5.687
 3: 2000  5.00    -0.1 -13.358 -11.428 -7.888 -4.431 -1.738 1.664 3.488 2.753 4.361  4.779 5.685
 4: 2000  5.50    -0.1 -13.220 -11.079 -7.377 -4.136 -1.483 1.656 3.418 2.759 4.355  4.753 5.638
 5: 2200  3.50    -0.1 -11.866  -9.557 -6.378 -3.612 -1.185 1.892 3.294 2.608 3.929  4.289 4.842
 6: 2200  4.50    -0.1 -11.845  -9.643 -6.348 -3.589 -1.132 1.874 3.310 2.648 3.947  4.305 4.939
 7: 2200  5.50    -0.1 -11.655  -9.615 -6.279 -3.508 -0.997 1.886 3.279 2.709 3.964  4.314 4.928
 8: 2500 -1.02    -0.1  -7.410  -7.624 -6.204 -3.854 -1.533 1.884 3.320 2.873 3.598  3.964 5.579
 9: 2500 -0.70    -0.1  -7.008  -7.222 -5.818 -3.618 -1.338 1.905 3.266 2.868 3.502  3.877 5.417
10: 2500 -0.29    -0.1  -6.526  -6.740 -5.357 -3.421 -1.215 1.927 3.216 2.870 3.396  3.781 5.247
11: 2500  5.50    -0.1  -9.518  -7.575 -5.010 -2.756 -0.511 1.959 3.057 2.642 3.472  3.756 4.265
12: 2800 -1.02    -0.1  -7.479  -7.386 -5.941 -3.716 -1.432 1.824 3.259 2.812 3.567  3.784 5.333
13: 2800 -0.70    -0.1  -7.125  -7.032 -5.596 -3.477 -1.231 1.822 3.218 2.813 3.479  3.717 5.229
14: 2800 -0.29    -0.1  -6.673  -6.580 -5.154 -3.166 -0.974 1.816 3.163 2.812 3.364  3.628 5.093
15: 2800  3.50    -0.1  -8.113  -6.258 -4.103 -2.209 -0.360 1.957 2.872 2.517 3.219  3.427 4.026
16: 2800  4.00    -0.1  -7.992  -6.099 -3.937 -2.076 -0.230 1.907 2.869 2.480 3.227  3.424 4.075
17: 2800  4.50    -0.1  -7.815  -6.051 -4.067 -2.176 -0.228 1.920 2.877 2.503 3.212  3.428 4.000
18: 2800  5.00    -0.1  -7.746  -6.018 -4.031 -2.144 -0.176 1.907 2.883 2.512 3.216  3.430 4.023
19: 3000 -0.70    -0.1  -7.396  -6.995 -5.605 -3.554 -1.293 1.787 3.172 2.759 3.474  3.588 5.052
20: 3000 -0.29    -0.1  -6.966  -6.565 -5.179 -3.249 -1.035 1.772 3.136 2.764 3.388  3.533 4.978
```

Notice, for example, how every `V` value has a unique `Teff`, `logg` combination.

Now, let's say I have two values:

```
input_Teff = 2300
input_log_g = 3.86
```

If we imagine all the (Teff, logg) combinations as grid points, for a given input point, I would like to find the four points closest to that input point.

```
point 1 (Teff1, logg1)
point 2 (Teff2, logg2)
point 3 (Teff3, logg3)
point 4 (Teff4, logg4)
```

then, calculate "distances" between my input point and the other points through Pythagoras (in this examples, three distances),

```
(Teff1, logg_1) -> d1 
(Teff2, logg_2) -> d2
(Teff3, logg_3) -> d3 
(Teff4, logg_4) -> d4 # NOTE: Teff and logg are different scales
```

next, get in this example, the `V` values in the rows of these points,

```
(Teff1, logg_1) -> V1 
(Teff2, logg_2) -> V2
(Teff3, logg_3) -> V3
(Teff4, logg_4) -> V4
```

And finally do a weighted average calculation

```
V = (d1V1+d2V2+d3V3+d4V4)/(d1+d2+d3+d4)
```

What would be a good way to do this in R?

Edit: https://www.dropbox.com/s/prbceabxmd25etx/lcb98cor.dat?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: sample data]

lets say your dataframe name is `teff_df`, and lets assume this way is to calculate phytagoras distances, (update -> find nearest distance between input and every point of `Teff` `logg`), note: I use min-max normalization to rescale the `Teff` and `logg` values:

```
min_max_norm <- function(x) {
    return(((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x))))
}
phytagoras <- function(a,b){
  return(a**2 + b**2)
}
```

First, calculate the Teff and logg rescale values between the input and all available grid points into a ranges of 0-1:

```
teff_with_input <- c(teff_df$Teff, 2300)
logg_with_input <- c(teff_df$logg, 3.86)
teff_rescale <- min_max_norm(teff_with_input)
logg_rescale <- min_max_norm(logg_with_input)
teff_input_rescale <- teff_rescale[length(teff_rescale)]
logg_input_rescale <- logg_rescale[length(logg_rescale)]
teff_rescale <- teff_rescale[-length(teff_rescale)]
logg_rescale <- logg_rescale[-length(logg_rescale)]
```

[image: input rescale]

[image: rescale value]

Second, calculate the differences between input and all grid point which already transformed to phytagoras values:

```
input_distance <- phytagoras(teff_input_rescale, logg_input_rescale)
my_phyta_dist <- phytagoras(teff_rescale, logg_rescale)
my_v_point <- teff_df[,which(colnames(teff_df)=="V")]
diff_input <- my_phyta_dist - input_distance

teff_df[order(abs(diff_input))[1:4],] #this will display which rows are nearest based by phytagoras distance calculation
```

[image: 4 nearest point in teff_df]

Third, extract the 4 nearest points, by the minimum differences of input and 4 points of `Teff` and `logg` combination grid

```
nearest_4rows <-  as.numeric(rownames(teff_df[order(abs(diff_input))[1:4],]))
nearest_4phyta_dist <- my_phyta_dist[nearest_4rows]
nearest_4v_point <- my_v_point[nearest_4rows]
```

[image: phyta dist and v_point in 4 nearest point]

and then finally, calculate final formula of weighted average calculation
`V = (d1V1+d2V2+d3V3+d4V4)/(d1+d2+d3+d4)`

```
product_dist <- nearest_4phyta_dist * nearest_4v_point
weighted_average <- sum(product_dist) / sum(nearest_4phyta_dist)
```

[image: weight average final]

Comment: What do you mean by `#4 point of index 4,5,6,7`? How does this relate to what I input (`input_Teff = 2300` and `input_log_g = 3.86`)?

Comment: thats only a 4 random point index of dataframe rows in a brief of examples. or do you mean you also need to match nearest point? if thats the case what is your specification of nearest point? does having 2 lower output teff and log_g and 2 higher output teff and log_g is your definition of nearest? or having 4 higher output is nearest?

Comment: and by nearest which variable are more important teff or logg_g?

Comment: Let us consider every `Teff` `logg` combination as a "point". We want to calculate the distance (using Pythagorean theorem) to EVERY point in the grid, then look at which four points are closest to our input point. `Teff` and `logg` are equally important, and notably on different scales, so we have to rescale first from 0 to 1.

Comment: okay, so in other words you want to compare nearest distance between the teff logg input to every point of the teff and logg variable?

Comment: Okay I updated my answers, based by your description

Comment: When I run your code with the input `Teff` and `logg` with the complete data table to test them out, the output of `nearest_4v_point` is, `6 NA NA NA`. Would you happen to know why this is? I edited my question to include the entire table.

Comment: what is the output of your `teff_df[order(abs(diff_input))[1:4],]` and `nearest_4rows`? nearest_4v_point should be the V value from your df that is nearest by phytagoras distances

Comment: I will add some results of screenshot from testing it with your sample data to make it easier to compare

Comment: You are testing it with the data from the dropbox link? I am getting `teff_input_rescale = 0.00625` and `logg_input_rescale = 0.7484663`. :/

Comment: Update: So when I just read the first 20 rows of my entire data frame, like what you do in your screenshots, I can reproduce everything up to `nearest_4phyta_dist` where it is `0.5928055 0.7167752 0.8525067 1.0000000`.

Comment: Yes. I only capable reproduce your issue based by your shared datasets. if this helps your problem, appreciate it if you can tick an accepted answer :)

Comment: Jovan Your answer does help, so I checked it off, but I still cannot get a weight average value besides `NA` :( Would you mind helping troubleshoot?

Comment: I think this might be because you still have NA values in your real datasets, have you double checked it? make sure you have no NA in your datasets

Comment: I just doubled checked - there are no NA values in the data set

Comment: Then in which point/calculation you start getting NA values?

Comment: `6 NA NA NA` is the output of `nearest_4v_point`. It is also worth noting that the closest four rows when printing `> teff_df[order(abs(diff_input))[1:4],]` are listed as `1 2 3 4` and all their Teff values are 16000.

Comment: honestly I cant really imagine how you can get that outcome without seeing directly your real datasets. I can only tell that theres irregular in either Teff, Logg, and V values that are may be different than the sample which causing getting 4 nearest point aren't successful.

Comment: I can help you look at it if you willing to share the datasets. So I can find which one make the NA issues, email me at jovanshadowz@gmail.com

Comment: The real data set is the dropbox link.

Comment: I checked directly to your data file, i get `-1.406 -1.415 -1.423 -1.438` for nearest_4v_point. and `teff_df[order(abs(diff_input))[1:4],]` shows rows of `357, 810,, 1263, 1719` I think why you get NA is that you fail to read the data correctly, in my case i use `teff_df <- read.table(file.choose(), header=TRUE)`

Comment: and also there is some typo in your .dat file, there is # in the beginning of file, delete and save it, then read the file to R so you're good to go